# AngularJs transclude input element into template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, transclusion

I want to insert(`transclude`) `<input>` element into `<div>` which is in template.

Problem is that I get: `Error: $compile:multidir Multiple Directive Resource Contention` and I not sure why, I would be thankful if someone can explain how should I improve my code, to make it working.

**Template:**

```
<div class="validatable-input">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-lg fa-times-circle': validatedField.$invalid, 'fa fa-lg fa-check-circle' : validatedField.$valid }" 
               ng-style="validatedField.$invalid ? {color: 'red'} : {color: 'green'}"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <small ng-if="validatedField.$invalid" ng-style="validatedField.$invalid ? { color: 'red'}: { color: 'green'}">{{errorMessage}}</small>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
loginApp.directive('inputValidationWrapper', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            validatedField: '=',
            errorMessage: '@'
        },
        template: '<ng-include src="contentUrl"/>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("validatedField.$touched", function () {
                if (scope.validatedField && scope.validatedField.$touched) {
                    scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                        scope.contentUrl = '../../pages/templates/validation-wrapper-tplt.html';
                    });
                    if (scope.validatedField.$valid) {
                        element.removeAttr('popover');
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true
    };
}]);
```

**Usage (Html):**

```
        <input-validation-wrapper validated-field=regForm.userName error-message="Username is required.">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="userName" ng-model="userName" required autofocus/>
        </input-validation-wrapper>
```

Comment: you need to make `replace: false,`

Comment: ok, this removed error, but nothing appears on DOM.

Comment: could you create a plunkr?

Comment: I made, but to say truth, I do know how to make it properly,
http://plnkr.co/edit/fzJGqwoGiwsPE3IIwpce?p=preview

Comment: Why do you need to load the template dynamically? Please have a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwWfXUdBGrfr9ANLWq74?p=preview) for a working demo of your code.

Comment: Thank that helped, probably I should get to know more bout templates.